Thriller black and white movie mainly set during a trial
It may or may not have been a movie by Hitchcock. It was shot in black and white, so I guess it may be something from the '60, or earlier. It wasn't a recent movie for sure.
It was about a trial in which the protagonist was either a famous lawyer or a judge who was prosecuting a man accused of murder. The whole plot revolved around how the wife of the suspect was able to defend the husband (who was actually guilty of the crime) by creating evidences of his innocence. In the end, the husband is deemed innocent thanks to the wife's intervention and just before leaving the courtroom (or around those moments) he told her that he still didn't love her and that she should have done it anyway, or something around those lines. The wife (with good reasons, if you ask me) then proceeds to shoot his lovely husband in front of the courthouse and is then arrested.
The protagonist then tells his assistant that he'll defend the woman during her trial.
I watched it in italian some years ago, but it was probably shot in english. 

This sounds very much like Billy Wilder's excellent Witness for the Prosecution from 1957, but she stabs him in the end.

It's that one, I remember she killed him somehow, for some reason I assumed he was shot. Feel free to answer :)

You're describing Billy Wilder's Witness for the Prosecution (1957), one of my favorite court dramas with the great Charles Laughton and Marlene Dietrich.

Esteemed criminal lawyer Sir Wilfrid Robarts has just returned to practice after suffering a heart attack and is supposed to be on a diet of bland civil suits. But the case of Leonard Vole, a charmer accused of murdering a rich middle-aged widow, proves irresistible --- particlularly when Sir Wilfrid meets the accused's wife, the remarkable Christine Vole. Christine will appear as a witness: not the defense, but for the prosecution. 

It ends like you said. Here's the trailer (where Laughton describes the film, a bit like Hitchcock):



